# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException / webdriver timeout execption in click action chrome drier

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below given exception in give code :

Getting web element using xpath, so should be present in dom, but still gets this exception.
Tried with implicit wait, and thread sleep also, didnt work.

Code:

```
 webElements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(variantSelectors.get(index)));
      for (WebElement webElement : webElements) {
        // move to variant url
        Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
        action.moveToElement(webElement).click().perform();
        Thread.sleep(extractionConfig.getWaitTime());
```

Exception :

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'Bhagwatis-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.177.68.108', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f5..., userDataDir: /var/folders/x7/mp7jd3q94wl...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.87, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

Comment: at which line you are getting stale element reference ?

Comment: You can use try catch block to handle that exception.

Comment: @cruisepandey 2nd last line.

Comment: @GautamBothra i should not get that exception . i know i can use try catch there to handle exception.

Answer (score 0):

DOM has been altered after clicking on first element in the list. so that you need to inspect / identify again. please add the following line at end of the for each loop as given below.

```
  webElements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(variantSelectors.get(index)));
```

in cod,

```
  webElements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(variantSelectors.get(index)));

  for (WebElement webElement : webElements) {
    // move to variant url
    Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
    action.moveToElement(webElement).click().perform();
    Thread.sleep(extractionConfig.getWaitTime());
    webElements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(variantSelectors.get(index)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);  
List<WebElement> alllinks = 
    webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("variantSelectors.get(index)));
for(int i=0 ; i<alllinks.size() ; i++) {
     int attempts = 0;
     while(attempts < 2) {
     try {
       List<WebElement> alllinks = 
        webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("variantSelectors.get(index)));
        action.moveToElement(webElement).click().perform();
        break;
       } 

    catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       }
      attempts++;
    }
```